# I am trying to refresh a set of UICollectionViews all placed on a UIScrollView by pulling down on the UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, refresh

I have multiple `UICollectionViews` all placed on a `UIScrollView`. I want to pull down on the `UIScrollView` (similar to Instagram and Twitter feed refreshers) and refresh the data in the `UICollectionViews`. However, what I tried hasn't worked.

Below is the code I tried implementing. When I run this and try to pull down on the `UIScrollView`. I am shown the dial that indicates refreshing, but nothing changes and "refresh" is never printed.

```
 var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
 override func viewDidLoad()  {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
      scrollView.bounces  = true
      refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
      refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPullToRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
      self.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
   }

  @objc func didPullToRefresh() {

     targetCollectionView.reloaddata()
     print("Refersh")

     // For End refrshing
     refreshControl.endRefreshing()  


   }
```

Comment: Check your contentsize height is less than to your UIScrollView, then it wont worked. Also note this point AllowBounceVertical = true and set UIScrollView delegate

Comment: try assigning like `scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl`

Comment: Yes, try Raghav7890 solution if you are targeting iOS 10 and above, and also Prasanth suggestion is on point, if your scrollview has  lower content size height than scrollview then it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Since there are multiple collection views inside scrollview, it may possible that the pull to refresh is not triggering on scrollview,(might be on collection view as multiple collection view are there)

**Possible Reason Why `didPullToRefresh` method is not calling?**

You have added the `UIRefreshControl` on scrollview. So when you are pulling down the view it is the collection view (not the scrollview, I think). That is the reason **"refresh" is never printed.**

**How to detect which view pulled for refresh?**

lets say you have 2 collection view and 1 scrollview on you self.view. so add `UIRefreshControl` on all the views like below...

```
//add refresh control on collection view 1
     let refreshController1 = UIRefreshControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 30))
    refreshController1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(colView1Refreshed), for: .valueChanged)
    collectionView1.refreshControl = refreshController1

//add refresh control on collection view 2
    let refreshController2 = UIRefreshControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 30))
    refreshController2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(colView2Refreshed), for: .valueChanged)
    collectionView2.refreshControl = refreshController2

//add refresh control on scrollview
    let refreshController3 = UIRefreshControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 30))
    refreshController3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scrollViewRefreshed), for: .valueChanged)
    scrollView.refreshControl = refreshController3
```

And then implement these methods to check which view is pulled.

```
@objc func colView1Refreshed() {
    print("collection view 1 pulled")
}

@objc func colView2Refreshed() {
    print("collection view 2 pulled")
}

@objc func scrollViewRefreshed() {
    print("collection view 3 pulled")
}
```

In this way you can identified which refresh control's action is triggred.

***NOTE: The above mention code is just an example. If you have more than 2 collection view then you need to add `UIRefreshControl` on all the other views to detect it.***